# How can I filter out expired records in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

For a new application I am using, the datamart creates a new record for every change to a record.  For example Sue Smith changes her name to Sue Jones, now I have two records for Sue.  Those changes occur multiple times and result in often hundreds of records for the one individual.  Each record also have a version effective date and version expiration date- ie
eff 8/10/23 exp 11/01/23, then a new record starting 11/1/23.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to properly filter out the old records so I can get a correct headcount?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you only want the latest record imported/loaded or do you want to count relevant record based on a date selection?

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the "version expiration date" to show only the current rows.  Typically it will either be null or some fixed date in the far future.